# How do you curry a built-in function for a boolean type (and set it to 1 or 0)?

Tags: perl, moose, currying

I thought I could curry a Boolean native type to set to true or false given a function call, but doesn't seem to work how I expected

**updated with traits**

```
    has 'Lock'    => ( 
        is => 'ro', 
        isa => 'Bool', 
        traits => ['Bool'],
        default => 0 ,
        reader  => 'isLocked', 
        handles => {
            lock     => [ set => 1 ],
            unlock => [ set => 0 ],
            flip     => 'toggle',

        }
  );
```

Comment: Please don't update questions with answers; they make your question much less useful to the rest of the world.

Comment: it wasnt that I was missing traits that was the problem it was how I was using set, so in effect -- I didnt because in my actual that wasnt the problem. But thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Bool](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aAttribute%3a%3aNative%3a%3aTrait%3a%3aBool) here, specified by `traits => ['Bool']`.

When all you have is `isa => 'Bool', default => 0`, your attribute doesn't hold an object. You can't call methods on the number 0, so it can't `handles` anything without help from a native trait.

From [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aAttribute%3a%3aNative): "Native delegations allow you to delegate to native Perl data structures as if they were objects." That means that when you use `handles` with them, they generate special methods that perform certain operations on the attribute other than calling a method on an object stored within the attribute. The Bool native trait provides `set`, `unset`, and `toggle` methods, which means you can do what you want with:

```
has 'Lock'    => ( 
    is => 'ro', 
    isa => 'Bool',
    traits => ['Bool'],
    default => 0 ,
    reader  => 'isLocked', 
    handles => {
        lock     => 'set',
        unlock   => 'unset',
        flip     => 'toggle',
    }
 );
```